# /sys/fs/pstore won't work on poco m3 android, is there a way to fix it?

Tags: android, linux, debugging, kernel, selinux

I'm trying to use pstore logs on my Poco M3. I tried everything. PSTORE configs are activated on the kernel, pstore module is loaded on the phone, phone is rooted, /sys/fs/pstore is mounted automatically but never contains anything.

```
130|citrus:/ # dmesg | grep pstore
[    0.094327] console [pstore-1] enabled
[    0.094468] pstore: Registered ramoops as persistent store backend
[    1.065975] pstore: Using compression: deflate
[   98.052156] type=1400 audit(1654268897.690:3752): avc: denied { read } for comm="ls" name="/" dev="pstore" ino=1197 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:pstorefs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
[   98.052450] type=1400 audit(1654268897.690:3753): avc: denied { open } for comm="ls" path="/sys/fs/pstore" dev="pstore" ino=1197 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:pstorefs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
```

it looks like selinux is blocking `ls` on `/sys/fs/pstore`. Is there a way to make it always allow `ls` on /sys/fs/pstore, even after reboot?

I already added `androidboot.selinux=permissive` to my boot command line and it's recognized on the phone:

```
130|citrus:/ # getenforce
Permissive
```

**UPDATE**: I just learned that permissive means just logging without blocking, so this is not blocking, my pstore is indeed empty. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

[image]/sys/fs/pstore is used very specifically - to persistently store crash files - kernel oops and last RAM console. So the fact it doesn't contain anything is actually good, in a way.

To see for yourself - simulate a panic. That'd require writing 'c' to /proc/sysrq_trigger (and possibly enabling that via /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq mask). The device will reboot, and on the boot you will see that the store files appear. (Note this has to be the boot immediately following the crash, because the files are cleared thereafter.

Incidentally - Re:SELinux , those AVC logs you showed are because SELinux denied the "ls" operation itself. That is a mandatory access control protection, which prevents reading the directory (even when it is empty). So that wouldn't change much.

Comment: I triggedred crashes, and nothing appears after reboot. also, I tried booting broken kernels and also can't see anything. Also, I found out that the selinux logs happened while on non root, so all good. anyways, can't make it work in any way

Comment: That's unusual and a bit unlikely. The dmesg output clearly states it's being used, and the file system is mounted. The problem is that pstore only persists across one reboot, before it gets wiped out. so if you use the sysrq and trigger a crash it's imperative you boot directly into root (and not, say, via adb reboot bootloadre). Then the console-ramoops will be there.

Comment: how do I boot directly into root? Can I change something in the command line?

Comment: I mean, command line arguments for the kernel

Comment: You'd need a patched kernel. You build a boot.img with magisk, then to pass the command line args you have to edit it further (imjtoool works well for that, though you can also patch via a hex editor). Presumably you already are booting to root if you flashed the boot.img and right after 'adb shell' you can 'su'

Comment: Yes I did that. I can use su inside, and I'm trying to read from /sys/fs/pstore with su as well

Comment: are you talking about patched boot.img or patchet kernel? Is my phone having root enough?

Comment: so you should be ok; like we said, /sys/fs/pstore will be populated immediately after reboot with (usually) one or (sometimes, depending on kernel build) two files. We added a snippet of the Android Internals (newandroidbook.com) book explaining this.

Comment: yes but the problem is that I actually want to have errors there, because I'm trying to boot a kernel that won't boot, so I need a way to debug, but pstore never ever works, not even when I trigger a crash.

Comment: my phone does not have `/proc/sysrq_trigger`, is there a CONFIG that I can enable?

Comment: if pstore isn't with any files, then it's not your kernel crashing - it's Android that isn't booting.  In other words, it's not a panic. So VERY likely your kernel IS booting, but Android doesn't (the difference is hard to tell without a console);. Without sysrq_trigger (which is, indeed, a KCONFIG_SYSRQ or something similar), you can't follow the test to crash the kernel.

Comment: I was able to use sysrq_trigger and it crashes but no log

Comment: that, then, means something isn't working as it should.. we still wager there IS a log somewhere , but Android picks it up early on successful boot. If this had been standard Linux, you could boot into single user mode, but that's not an option with Android.